# aggregate array based on month and year

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapreduce

I have an array like this

```
var data = [[1411151400000,1686],[1428604200000,1686],[1411151400000,1686]....]
```

I need to group this data based on month and sum up the data for that month.

the final output should look like.

```
 var final = [[timestamp for month, sum of value of that month],[]]
```

Below is the code which i tried, But It not giving correct results, I am thinking if it can be done by Map reduce of array

```
if(aggregatorType === "month")
{

        sum = 0;

            $.each(datalooper,function(key,value){
                var date =  new Date(value[0]);
                var month = date.toString("MMMM");
                var year = date.toString("yyyy");
                var temparr = [];
                var lastdate = 0;
                if(!iterator[month+"_"+year]){
                    iterator[month+"_"+year] = value;
                    temparr.push(value[0]);
                    temparr.push(sum);
                    if(sum != 0)
                        newArr.push(temparr);
                    sum = 0;
                }
                else{
                    sum = sum+ value[1];
                    lastdate=value[0];
                }
            })
                totalObj.push(newArr);
            newArr = [];
            iterator = {};

    }
    return totalObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution which  gets year and month and groups the values to it.

The [`Date#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) has no parameters to set.

The year and month is retrieved with [`Date#getYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) and [`Date#getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth).

```js
var data = [[1411151400000, 1686], [1428604200000, 1686], [1411151400000, 1686]],
    grouped = function (array) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            var date = new Date(a[0]),
                month = date.getMonth() + 1,
                key = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month;
            if (!o[key]) {
                o[key] = [key, 0];
                r.push(o[key]);
            }
            o[key][1] += a[1];
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

> var final = [[timestamp for month, sum of value of that month],[]]

Find months first

```
var newData = [];
var months = {};
data.forEach(function(value){
   var date = new Date(value[0]);
   date.setDate(1);
   date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
   var month = date.getTime();
   if( !months[ month ] )
   {
      months[ month ] = 0;
   }
   months[ month ] += value[1];
});
```

Now turn it into an array

```
newData = Object.keys( months ).map( function(key){ return [ key, months[key] ]; } );
```

This will give you the output in the format you are looking for.

Comment: Still have to parse the months from dates to create object keys

Comment: @charlietfl his data array items first value (`1411151400000`) is a timestamp for a specific month. He can get the month and year from it.

Comment: That's my point. That date is Sept 19, 2014 so the answer doesn't indicate parsing it into a month

Comment: @charlietfl got it, let me see

Comment: @charlietfl please check now

Comment: Makes more sense now

Answer (score 0):

**Probably be easier to create an object and then map back to your desired result object**, here have the objects mapped by month and year with the stacks like you have

```
var mappings = datalooper.map(function(v) {
        var nDate = new Date(v[0]);
        return {
            year: nDate.getYear(),
            month: nDate.getMonth(),
            data: v[1]
        };
    }).reduce(function(result, curr) {

        if (result[curr.year] === undefined) {
            result[curr.year] = {}
        }

        if (result[curr.year][curr.month] === undefined) {
            result[curr.year][curr.month] =[];
        }

        result[curr.year][curr.month].push(data

        return result;
});
/*if you want to put them in an array do the following
but not sure how you will keep track of which month is which */
return Object.keys(mappings)
      .map(function(v){ 

           return Object.keys(mappings[v])
                        .map(function(v){ return v ; } );
      });
```